# String.replaceAll Strange Behaviour

Tags: java, regex, string

```
String s = "hi                  hello";
s = s.replaceAll("\\s*", " ");
System.out.println(s);
```

I have the code above, but I can't work out why it produces

```
 h i  h e l l o
```

rather than

```
 hi hello
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `+` quantifier to match 1 or more spaces instead of `*`: -

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
```

`\\s*` means match 0 or more spaces, and will match an empty character before every character and is replaced by a space.

Comment: +1 Instead of "between", I would say "before" as it will match before the first character.

Answer (score 9):

The `*` matches 0 or more spaces, I think you want to change it to `+` to match 1 or more spaces.