# Passing escape sequences in the args[] array on Windows

Tags: java, regex, windows, command-line-arguments

I was reading SCJP guide, and found the following question, it's looks very easy and might be easy for someone. But, i was really stuck to find out the solution.

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class study{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Pattern p = Pattern.compile(args[0]);
      Matcher m = p.matcher(args[1]);
      boolean b=false;
      while(b=m.find()){
      System.out.print(m.start()+" "+m.group());
     }
    }

}
```

In that question the command line argument was given like

```
java study "\d*" ab34ef
```

And, said what would be the ouput, my guess was **334** or **234** and it was in that option. But, answer (***on Windows***) was **01234456**. So, my first question is **How ??**

Now, people say, why didn't you tried. Then, i will say, Yes i did. But, in my case I didn't get any output on my screen. Then, i tried to figure out considering all type of input and their values.

[image]

In the above screenshot, second output shown, when i included `System.out.print(args[0]+" "+args[1]);` inside main method.

Even, i changed the command line to this

```
java study "\\d*" ab34ef
```

Then also, i didn't get any output. So, anyone explain all this thing .

**OUTPUT==**

```
java study "\d*" ab34ef
No output
java study "\\d*" ab34ef
No output
```

Then i add `System.out.print(args[0]+" "+args[1]);` inside main method.

```
java study "\d*" ab34ef
\Document and Setting ab34ef
java study "\\d*" ab34ef
\\d* ab34ef
```

**Note :** No output means it is not showing anything.

Comment: Related - [string-replaceall-strange-behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960302/string-replaceall-strange-behaviour/13960331#13960331)

Comment: Please post the output you got here, rather than posting screen shots. I can't see any screen shot there.

Comment: @RohitJain you can i tried this one also. in my last attempt i.e. `java study "\\d*" ab34ef`

Comment: I copied your code withou modification. And I did this:
`java study "\\d*" ab34ef` the output was `0 1 2 344 5 6`.

Comment: @RohitJain through the screenshot, i have shown the output. So that, no one can say, i'm getting this or that.

Comment: @RohitJain in that screenshot, first time i didn't get any output, but once i added `System.out.print(args[0]+" "+args[1]);` in main method. then in second time i got some output, which is also shown in same screenshot.

Comment: @rockskull i knew it, someone will definitely say this thing that, he is getting output. But, to be very frank. I'm not getting anything. That's why, i put the screenshot.

Comment: @coders.. I think I said - `I can't see the screenshot`. So, you should not again point me towards your screen shot. Why don't you post your output here? We'll believe you.

Comment: @coders FWIW, I get the same outputs as you, running Java 7. I can't understand why `\Documents and Settings` is output.

Comment: I know. sometimes happens. But I really just copied and pasted your code here and it worked with the double slashes (with and without the quote).

wich java SDK are you using ? (I'm using java 6 here)

Comment: @rockskull java version 1.7.0_09

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually what happens is, when you pass `\d*` as command line argument, it is treated as `\d` followed by `*` wildcard. So, the argument is replaced by all the files starting with `\d` in that directory. (This behaviour happens on `Windows`. Though I don't know about `Linux`, as I haven't used it).

So, you are not passing the regular expression, rather the file/directory names starting with `\d` in to your program.

Try to print the arguments in your code: -

```
System.out.println(args[0] + " : " + args[1]);
```

This will give you some file/directory names starting with `\d...`

---

**Workaround: -**

If you want to pass regex, you can use a work around. Pass `" \d*"` as regex with a space in the front, and in your code, use `args[0].trim()` or `args[0].replace(" ", "");` instead of `args[0]`.

So, call it as: -

```
java Foo " \d*" ab34ef
```

And change your code to: -

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(args[0].replace(" ", ""));
Matcher m = p.matcher(args[1]);
```

This will do the job for you.

---

Now that was the problem of passing Regex through command line.

As for why you are getting that output, Check out this answer - [string-replaceall-strange-behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960302/string-replaceall-strange-behaviour/13960331#13960331), which is about similar problem. You will get an idea of why this is happening.

Comment: +1 I will delete my answer, wasn't sure if you were going to post this.

Comment: @DuncanJones.. Ah! No problem. I was on my way.

Comment: @RohitJain at least now, i'm getting some output. But, the problem is answer is `01234456` but, i'm getting `2 33 4` :( Even, i added `trim` method.

Comment: @coders.. Did you made both of those changes? Are you passing `" \d*"`? And using `args[0].trim()`? I'm getting the required output - `01234456`.

Comment: @RohitJain `trim()` doesn't make any change. I mean, it shows same output with/without `trim`.

Comment: @RohitJain yes now, i got the answer. Please remove args[0].trim()` from your answer and add this args[0].replace(" ", "")` on your answer. Please also provide little explanation.

Comment: @coders.. `trim()` wasn't working because, you might be giving spaces in between - `"\d *"`, but you needed to give space at the ends - `" \d*"`. `trim()` removes the whitespaces from the ends.

Comment: @Coders.. And regarding the output you got, I have already referred a link to my old answer in your question. Also, you can see other answer here, which explains you why you got that output. That's all because `\d*` will match `empty string` before every character.

Comment: @coders. And for more surprise try printing this: - `System.out.println("abc".startsWith(""));` and see what you get. You will understand then what is happening.

Comment: @RohitJain i will. I just said, So that, later anyone can refer the same answer. Nevertheless i'm accepting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

i got the result, you wanted, with

```
java study "\d*" ab34ef
```

but maybe try the same, as `Rohit Jain` commented:

```
java study "\\d*" ab34ef
```

but it should work with your line! (on linux it does, maybe it's a windows problem)

Comment: you can see, in my question, even i tried the same. But,still i didn't get any output.

Comment: which java version do you use?  type `java -version`

Comment: The problem is in windows command line : - `\d*` is taken as `\d` followed by wild card, and will return all the files starting with `\d`. So, it is not read as Regex. You can try passing `\d *` with space in between, and in code use `args[0].replace(" ", "")`

Comment: @RohitJain Post that as an answer?

Comment: @joerg java version 1.7.0_09

Comment: It's ecxataly what @Rohit Jain I've printed the args, and i'm getting the file names in linux. Unless I quote them, them it works, with one, two or with none slashes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
java study d* ab34ef
```

Here is why.

Escape sequences are for the Java compiler, The compiler will see, for example, a '\' followed by a 'n', and replace them both with a single newline character. Escape sequences have no meaning at all to Java when a program is running; they only mean something to the compiler when they appear in source code.

Embedding special characters into the arguments to a Java program is actually not a Java issue at all -- it's an operating system issue.

If you want to do the same thing from your source you have to pass the string like below.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d*");
Matcher m = p.matcher("ab34ef");
```

If you want to run via comman line just passing without escape characters will do

```
 d* ab34ef
```

Use some IDE like *Eclipse* and debug to find what exactly its being passed.

Comment: I tried here withou slashes (JDK 6, linux) and didn't worked. Just with the double slashes.

Comment: Can you debug and check what exactly is being passed to args[0] and args[1]?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first part of your question, the regular expression `\d*` matches *zero* or more digits, i.e. one of the things it is allowed to match is the empty string.  Thus given the input string

```
ab34ef
```

the pattern matches

- the empty string at position 0
- the empty string at position 1
- the string `34` at position 2
- the empty string at position 4
- the empty string at position 5
- the empty string at position 6

which explains the expected answer.